# Model Imaging Order with FHIR Resoruces

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm modeling imaging order with FHIR resource, and facing structural decision how to align imaging order information model in DICOM / HL7 V2 with FHIR. In DICOM / HL7 V2, an imaging order is modeled at 3 levels:
- Order ... a clinician's request for imaging service
- Requested Procedure ... a (reportable and billable) imaging service radiology dept offers to fulfill a clinical imaging order
- Procedure Step ... a (schedulable and performable) task which contributes to the completion of requested procedure
Here is my proposal of align the DICOM / V2 model with FHIR:
Order resource represents an Order
DiagnosticOrder resource represents a Requested Procedure
DiagnosticOrder.Item represents the Procedure Steps planned / scheduled / performed in the Requested Procedure
In the course of fulfilling a clinical order, a DiagnosticOrder resource will be updated to contain increasing details. There are information gaps in these existing resources (Order and DiagnosticOrder) which can be extended. I really like to get feedback and input whether this *structural* mapping makes sense, or I missed / misinterpret anything of the FHIR model? Any inputs are highly appreciated ... thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that makes sense. But such a general question - that's a general answer. it might change as we start discussing which specific things the "order" is, as opposed to the requested procedure.